# Postman выводит не ожидаемый ответ на запрос

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

При запуске приложения (код дефолтного контроллера):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему постмен может не видеть данную ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все дело было в этой штуке (было `on`)

Comment: Как порой бывает полезно почитать то, что пишется в ошибке...